# passing data from fragment child viewpager to the parent viewpager

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm new to Android. So forgive me, if my question is silly or redundant. or I'll explain again if the question is not very clear.

The problem I'm facing is that I have an Activity on which I'm inflating a fragmentA.

This fragmentA holds a viewpager in it. the Viewpager has fragmentA1 and FragmentA2 in it.

Now, clicking a textView in fragmentA1, will give birth to FragmentB which is holding another ViewPager with 4 fragments in it. Namely FragmentB1,B2,B3,B4. All these fragments have RecyclerViews in them. with their respective RecyclerView Adapters.

Now, upon clicking on any list item on lest's FragmentB2. I want the data from that list item to be sent back to the **FragmentA1**. Similarly, I want to send listItem data from any of the fragments of the child viewpager i.e. FragmentB1,B2,B3,B4 to be sent to the **FragmentA1**. which is in the parent fragment's viewpager.

Could anyone please help me with this problem. I've tried various solutions from Stackoverflow but had no luck so far. Today is my second day working on this and I'm still stuck on this problem.

I've just saved the app from crashing with the following code:

```
holder.chooseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mRecyclerOnClickHandler.onClick(combo.get(position).getRs());
                Intent intent = new Intent(mFragmentActivity, mFragmentActivity.getClass());
                intent.putExtra("planPrice", combo.get(position).getRs());
                mFragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0).onActivityResult(
                        mFragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0).getTargetRequestCode(), RESULT_OK, intent);

                mFragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            }
        });
```

But I'm not able to pass the data.

Please help me with this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: You can use setTargerFragment() method

Comment: Or you can also use ViewModel it will be easier

Answer (score 0):

Create class which extends ViewModel

```
public class SharedViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private final MutableLiveData<String> priceLiveData = new MutableLiveData<String>();

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        selected.setValue(price);
    }

    public LiveData<Item> getPrice() {
        return priceLiveData;
    }
}
```

set the value of price in FragmentB1,FragmetB2,FragmentB3,FragmentB4 adapter

```
public class FragmentB1Adapter... {

     FragmentActivity activity;

     // here we need FragmentActivity so add it in construction
     FragmentB1Adapter(FragmentActivity activity){
          this.activity=activity;
     }

    //add this in onBindViewHolder
    private SharedViewModel model=newViewModelProvider(activity).get(SharedViewModel.class);


     //on button click
    holder.chooseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            model.setPrice(price);
        });
    }
}
```

Fragment where you want the value

```
public class FragmentA1 extends Fragment {

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        //other code

         //get value of price
        SharedViewModel model = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        model.getPrice().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), { new Observer<String>()       {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(String price) {
           //here you got your price
        });
    }


}
```

Hope this helps!